# How to transfer entire iTunes Connect Account's portfolio of apps to another entity?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

There are many answers out there on how to transfer individual apps, but none that I could find on how to transfer an entire account. I'm exploring this as a workaround to the issue where Apple won't let me move an app that has iCloud entitlements. Even if you remove the entitlement, as long as the app has had it in the past, it can't be transferred.

One idea is to add another user as an admin on my iTunes Connect, and then have them remove me. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to transfer a portfolio of apps. You can only transfer apps one-by-one and have the already mentioned restrictions. It's possible to change the team agent/account owner at least for company accounts.

If you have a personal account, this might not be possible. I had an issue with a personal developer account (account owner Apple ID no longer found in Apple's database) and they were able to change the email, but I had to prove that I'm the same person.

In any way, might be best to contact https://developer.apple.com/contact/ for that.